# Running multiple if statements within one function in a HTML game

Tags: javascript, css, web, 2d-games

So far in this game, I've made it possible to check wall and paddle collisions, and then respond by running an animation to redirect the ball. However, I keep falling down when it comes to checking a lack of collisions. Neither `else` nor `else if` statements work, and secondary if statements fail to work as well - either within the main function or as a separate event. I've covered pretty much every possibility here, but I'm hoping one of you guys (mega-dependable as you are) can help solve this.

Example of collision code (separate functions):

```
var BallStop7 = function(){
    setTimeout(BallStop8, 850);
    setTimeout(Check1, 1000);
    //setTimeout(Check1, 1000);    
    if(document.getElementById('Paddle2').style.top=="251px");
    {
        document.getElementById('BallRebound6').id='BallRebound7';
        document.getElementById('BallRebound7').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
    };  

};

var BallStop8 = function(){
    /**/ 
    document.getElementById('BallRebound7').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
    if(document.getElementById('Paddle1').style.top=="251px"){
        if(confirm("Draw. Would you like to try again?")){
            window.location="pingpongwars.tumblr.com";
        };
        document.getElementById('BallRebound7').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";    
    };
};


var Check1 = function(){
    if(document.getElementById('BallRebound7').style.left=="13.739665985107422px");{    
        alert("Player Two Wins");
        document.getElementById('BallRebound7').style.visibility="hidden";
    };
};
```

Main function

```
var BallStop4 = function(){
    //setTimeout(BallStop5, 370);
    if(document.getElementById('Paddle1Return').style.top=="9px");
    {
        document.getElementById('BallRebound3').id='BallRebound4';
        document.getElementById('BallRebound4').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
    };

    if(document.getElementById('BallRebound3').style.left=="30px"){
        alert("Player Two Wins");
        document.getElementById('BallRebound3').style.visibility="hidden";
    }
    BallStop5();
};
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbMCC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra semicolons in your code:

```
if(document.getElementById('Paddle2').style.top=="251px");
                                                         ^ = empty statement
{ /* A block of code */ }
```

In example above, if truthy, it executes an empty statement, and the codeblock will be executed anyway, despite of the result of the comaprison. Just remove all semicolons after `if`s.

`if` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement)

Also code blocks should not end with semicolon, unless they are a part of declaration or definition.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but the animations for the rebounds don't fire without them.

Comment: I think that's because there are very strict conditions for coordinates, rather use `offsetLeft` or  `offsetTop` and `>=` or `<=` instead of `style` and `==`. With ending semicolons those ifs are totally useless.

Comment: Got a bit confused with the last comment (I had another game that was ZOMG OVERCOMPLICATED, so I must have mixed it up with this one). Anyways, thanks for the advice :D